# How to code multiple datasets in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I have a report where I need the same data, but for four separate date ranges.  Currently this data is based on one month, so it's just one dataset.  But now I am trying to do this with four separate datasets, where each one is filtered on each of the four date ranges.  I setup my WHILE loop to loop thru all four dates.  But I'm having trouble now with distinct naming these datasets.  Is this the best way to do this?  It looks like if I used multiple datatables for one dataset, I'd have to define each datatable column.  Here is my current dataset commandstring:

```
commandstring = "SELECT Batch_Records.Part_Number, Batch_Records.Lot_Number, Batch_Records.Date_Received, " & _
                                           "IsNull([Date_Completed], [Review_Date]) AS CompleteDate, Batch_Records.Error, " & _
                                           "Batch_Records.[Group], Batch_Records.MFG, Batch_Records.MFG2, Batch_Records.QC, Batch_Records.QC2, " & _
                                           "QC_CODES.CODE_DESC " & _
                                           "FROM EXCEL.Batch_Records LEFT JOIN EXCEL.QC_CODES ON Batch_Records.Part_Number = QC_CODES.CODE_ID " & _
                                           "WHERE (Batch_Records.[Group]" & TheGroup & " AND Batch_Records.Date_Received > '" & arrWeekYear(i, j).ToString("d") & "' AND Batch_Records.Date_Received < '" & arrWeekYear(i + 7, j).ToString("d") & "')"
```

Comment: Why can't you just do four different queries for the four dates ranges you are interested in parameterising the start and end dates as required?

Comment: Agreed with Matt. Parameterize the start and end date and create a stored procedure. And keep the information in 4 `DataTable`s inside one `DataSet`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you want 4 ranges in one query:

extend the WHERE (and watch out for the brackets...)

```
"WHERE (Batch_Records.[Group]" & TheGroup & 
" AND (Batch_Records.Date_Received > '" & arrWeekYear(i1, j).ToString("d") & "' AND Batch_Records.Date_Received < '" & arrWeekYear(i1 + 7, j).ToString("d") &
") or (Batch_Records.Date_Received > '" & arrWeekYear(i2, j).ToString("d") & "' AND Batch_Records.Date_Received < '" & arrWeekYear(i2 + 7, j).ToString("d") &
") or (Batch_Records.Date_Received > '" & arrWeekYear(i3, j).ToString("d") & "' AND Batch_Records.Date_Received < '" & arrWeekYear(i3 + 7, j).ToString("d") &
") or (Batch_Records.Date_Received > '" & arrWeekYear(i4, j).ToString("d") & "' AND Batch_Records.Date_Received < '" & arrWeekYear(i4 + 7, j).ToString("d") &
"'))"
```

Or if you want to have 4 sets of output, create a parameterized query. Run it 4 times just updating the parameter values. Thus you have no naming problems as you have only 1 query.